# Create dynamic switchery

Tags: jquery, html, switchery

I want to create dynamic switchery and create and button object with jquery and some dynamic variable for this then I want the Html object to append to Html I can't do it below link is my code
Visit jsfiddle.net/eu3a0k3m/2/

my js codes:

```
var count = 3;
$("#btn").click(function(){
    CreateInlineChildWithSwitchery(++count);
});
function CreateInlineChildWithSwitchery (countOfChilds){

      var Integer_LastSwitcheryId = count;

      var btn = $('<input type="checkbox" id="js-switch' + Integer_LastSwitcheryId + '" class="js-switch' + Integer_LastSwitcheryId + ' js-check-change' + Integer_LastSwitcheryId + ' col-lg-3" data-switchery="true">');
console.log(btn)
$('#all-encyclopedia').append(
        $("#tpl ").html() 
                                  .replace(/{switchery}/g,btn)
      );

      eval("elem" + Integer_LastSwitcheryId.toString() + "=document.querySelector('#js-switch"+Integer_LastSwitcheryId.toString()+"')");

      eval("switchery" + Integer_LastSwitcheryId.toString() +"={elem" + Integer_LastSwitcheryId.toString() + ",  color: '#1AB394',secondaryColor: '#688ab0'}");

      eval("changeCheckbox" + Integer_LastSwitcheryId.toString() + "=document.querySelector('.js-check-change"+Integer_LastSwitcheryId.toString()+"')");

      eval("changeField" + Integer_LastSwitcheryId.toString() + "=document.querySelector('.js-check-change-field"+Integer_LastSwitcheryId.toString()+"')");


  }


  for(i=1;i<4;i++)
      CreateInlineChildWithSwitchery(count++);
```

my Html codes:

```
<script type="text/tpl" id="tpl">
{switchery}
</script>
<button id="btn">insert Switchery</button>
<div id="all-encyclopedia"></div>
```

Comment: Hi alireza, you need to include the code in your post here on Stack Overflow - don't just link to a 3rd party site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `eval`. just call the `Switchery` constructor after you inserted the checkbox into the page.

```js
var count = 3;
$("#btn").click(function() {
  CreateInlineChildWithSwitchery(++count);
});

function CreateInlineChildWithSwitchery(id) {
  var btn = $('<input>').attr({
    id: 'js-switch' + id,
    type: 'checkbox',
    class: ['js-switch' + id, 'js-check-change' + id, 'col-lg3'].join(" "),
  }).data({
    switchery: true,
  })[0]

  $('#all-encyclopedia').append(
    $("#tpl").html().replace(/{switchery}/g, btn.outerHTML));

  new Switchery($('#' + 'js-switch' + id)[0], {
    color: '#1AB394',
    secondaryColor: '#688ab0'
  })
}


for (i = 1; i < 4; i++)
  CreateInlineChildWithSwitchery(count++);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/switchery/0.8.2/switchery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/switchery/0.8.2/switchery.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<script type="text/tpl" id="tpl">
  {switchery}
</script>
<button id="btn">insert Switchery</button>
<div id="all-encyclopedia"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The button code you're replacing the string with should be a string, not a jquery object.

```js
var count = 3;
$("#btn").click(function() {
  CreateInlineChildWithSwitchery(count);
});

function CreateInlineChildWithSwitchery(countOfChilds) {

  var Integer_LastSwitcheryId = count;

  var btn = '<input type="checkbox" id="js-switch' + Integer_LastSwitcheryId + '" class="js-switch' + Integer_LastSwitcheryId + ' js-check-change' + Integer_LastSwitcheryId + ' col-lg-3" data-switchery="true">';
  console.log(btn)
  console.log($('#tpl').html())
  $('#all-encyclopedia').append(
    $("#tpl").html()
    .replace(/{switchery}/g, btn)
  );

  eval("elem" + Integer_LastSwitcheryId.toString() + "=document.querySelector('#js-switch" + Integer_LastSwitcheryId.toString() + "')");

  eval("switchery" + Integer_LastSwitcheryId.toString() + "={elem" + Integer_LastSwitcheryId.toString() + ",  color: '#1AB394',secondaryColor: '#688ab0'}");

  eval("changeCheckbox" + Integer_LastSwitcheryId.toString() + "=document.querySelector('.js-check-change" + Integer_LastSwitcheryId.toString() + "')");

  eval("changeField" + Integer_LastSwitcheryId.toString() + "=document.querySelector('.js-check-change-field" + Integer_LastSwitcheryId.toString() + "')");


}


for (i = 1; i < 4; i++)
  CreateInlineChildWithSwitchery(count++);
```

```html
<link href="https://alireza-salehi.ir/switchery/switchery.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://alireza-salehi.ir/switchery/switchery.js"></script>
<script type="text/tpl" id="tpl">
  {switchery}
</script>
<button id="btn">insert Switchery</button>
<div id="all-encyclopedia">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code to below :

HTML  :

```
<link href="https://alireza-salehi.ir/switchery/switchery.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://alireza-salehi.ir/switchery/switchery.js"></script>
<script type="text/tpl" id="tpl">
{switchery}
</script>
<button id="btn">insert Switchery</button>
<div id="all-encyclopedia">
  <input type="checkbox" id="js-switch1" class="js-switch1 js-check-change1 col-lg-3" data-switchery="true">
</div>
```

js:

```
var count = parseInt($("[data-switchery=true]:last").attr('id')[$("[data-switchery=true]:last").attr('id').length-1]) + 1;

var elem1 = document.querySelector('#js-switch1');
var switchery1 = new Switchery(elem1,
{
  color: '#1AB394',
  secondaryColor: '#688ab0'
});


$("#btn").click(function() {
  CreateInlineChildWithSwitchery(++count);
});

function CreateInlineChildWithSwitchery(countOfChilds) {

  var Integer_LastSwitcheryId = count;

  var btn = '<input type="checkbox" id="js-switch' + Integer_LastSwitcheryId + '" class="js-switch' + Integer_LastSwitcheryId + ' js-check-change' + Integer_LastSwitcheryId + ' col-lg-3" data-switchery="true">';

  $('#all-encyclopedia').append(
    $("#tpl").html()
    .replace(/{switchery}/g, btn)
  );

  eval("elem" + Integer_LastSwitcheryId.toString() + "=document.querySelector('#js-switch" + Integer_LastSwitcheryId.toString() + "')");

  eval("switchery" + Integer_LastSwitcheryId.toString() + "={elem" + Integer_LastSwitcheryId.toString() + ",  color: '#1AB394',secondaryColor: '#688ab0'}");
        console.log(window[ "switchery" + Integer_LastSwitcheryId.toString() ])
  eval("changeCheckbox" + Integer_LastSwitcheryId.toString() + "=document.querySelector('.js-check-change" + Integer_LastSwitcheryId.toString() + "')");

  eval("changeField" + Integer_LastSwitcheryId.toString() + "=document.querySelector('.js-check-change-field" + Integer_LastSwitcheryId.toString() + "')");


}


for (i = 1; i < 4; i++)
  CreateInlineChildWithSwitchery(count++);
```

the first button of elements changes to Switchery and other not changed.

Visit: jsfiddle.net/eu3a0k3m/4

Answer (score 0):

with change blow section of code

```
eval("switchery" + Integer_LastSwitcheryId.toString() + "={elem" + Integer_LastSwitcheryId.toString() + ",  color: '#1AB394',secondaryColor: '#688ab0'}");
```

To:

```
var swicheryy = new Switchery(window[ "elem" + Integer_LastSwitcheryId.toString() ],{
  color: '#1AB394',
  secondaryColor: '#688ab0'
});
```

my problem is solved

Visit: jsfiddle.net/eu3a0k3m/5/